# How to apply merge in single table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update my table using merge. So when an employee joins another company then its new (date of joining) will be updated as (date of exit) in his previous entry. constraints `(((there is no unique id and name)))(((sno, ename, dept, comp, doj, doe)))` these are the attributes in table emp.

This is the table I have to update.

```
Sno ENAME   COMP    DEPT    DOJ         DOE 
-----------------------------------------------
1   rock    mi      it  10-AUG-18    -  
2   dock    apple   it  12-AUG-18    -  
3   rock    google  it  01-AUG-70    -  
4   dock    samsung it  26-AUG-89    -
```

After applying merge it should look like.

```
Sno ENAME   COMP    DEPT    DOJ         DOE 
-----------------------------------------------
1   rock    mi      it  10-AUG-18    01-AUG-70  
2   dock    apple   it  12-AUG-18    26-AUG-89  
3   rock    google  it  01-AUG-70    -  
4   dock    samsung it  26-AUG-89    -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use merge with a subquery:

```
merge into t using
      (select t.*, lead(doj) over (partition by ename order by doj) as next_doj
       from t
      ) tt
      on tt.sno = t.sno and tt.next_doj is not null
when matched then update
    set doe = next_doj;
```

You can also express this using a subquery and `update`:

```
update t
    set doe = (select min(t2.doe)
               from t tt
               where tt.ename = t.ename and
                     tt.doe > t.doe
              );
```

Comment: IF i have to do it using source table and target table using merge.

Comment: where initially target table is empty

Comment: @TanmaySwami . . . You would have a different question and `insert` would be more appropriate.

Comment: MERGE INTO emp1 x
USING (SELECT empno, ename, company, dept, doj, doe, valid  FROM emp) y
ON (x.enmae  = y.ename)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    
UPDATE emp M1
SET M1.doe = (SELECT doj FROM (SELECT M2.doj, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M2.ename ORDER BY M2.doj DESC) AS RN 
FROM emp M2 
WHERE M1.ename = M2.ename
AND M1.company <> M2.company
AND M2.doj > M1.doj
) WHERE RN = 1) - 1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(empno, ename, company, dept, doj, doe, valid)  
    VALUES(y.empno, y.ename, y.company, y.dept, y.doj, y.doe, y.valid); --------I have problem in when matched statement.

Comment: @TanmaySwami . . . That `merge` is a bit different from what is in this answer.  Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use update in such case as there might be issue with merge statement in such cases.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE M1
SET M1.DOE = (SELECT DOJ FROM (SELECT M2.DOJ, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M2.ENAME ORDER BY M2.DOJ) AS RN 
FROM MYTABLE M2 
WHERE M1.ENAME = M2.ENAME
AND M1.COMP <> M2.COMP
AND M2.DOJ < M1.DOJ
) WHERE RN = 1)
```

Also, you can use WHERE clause in UPDATE statement to restrict the records which do not have changed their job or records with their first job to avoid unnecessary update with nulls.

Cheers!!

Comment: According to your code new doj is updated in all existing doe (for the same employee name)


Sno ENAME COMP DEPT DOJ         DOE 
1 rock mi it 10-AUG-18 01-AUG-70 
2 rock apple it 12-AUG-18 01-AUG-70  
3 rock google it 01-AUG-70  -  
 

it should be updated as such 

Sno ENAME COMP DEPT DOJ         DOE 
1 rock mi it 10-AUG-18    12-AUG-18 
2 rock apple it 12-AUG-18    01-AUG-70 
3 rock google it 01-AUG-70  -

Comment: Remove DESC from ORDER BY and change > to < in last condition

Comment: Updated the answer according to above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `update` statement including a `select` statement with `with..as` clause containing `lag() over (..)` and `max() over (..)` analytic functions of which will have results to be used as matching criteria for the nested `select` statement.

```
update tab t2
   set t2.doe = ( with t1 as ( 
                         select t.*, 
                                lag(doj) over (partition by ename order by doj) as lg_doj,
                                max(doj) over (partition by ename order by doj) as mx_doj
                           from tab t
                    )  
                    select lg_doj
                      from t1
                     where t1.ename = t2.ename
                       and t1.mx_doj = t2.doj 
                     );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=459642282e634d850b00c6ff9cb06cde)</kbd>

*but it's not suitable to track the employees by their name, you should use employee ID instead.*